# Trying to update some tables in PostgreSQL in unbound cursor/refcursor

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to update two tables from an unbound ref cursor records which basically based on these two tables only. how can I achieve it? Once I am trying to fetch a unique column identifier and passing it in loop in one of the table it's not working. Is it really possible in PostgreSQL ? The below updates in Loop, i need to prepare dynamically but not able to prepare bcos of source_record.A_ID can't prepare on the fly. if I concatenate, It not pass actual values from above cursor. Here is attached tables, joined with TPID and AMT(settlement_amt)

[TABLE-A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67xns.png)
[TABLE-B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOScN.png)

```
declare
V_SOURCE_QUERY VARCHAR(1000):='SELECT A.ID A_ID, B.ID B_ID FROM A A, B B     WHERE some_condition';
begin

OPEN CUR_SOURCE FOR EXECUTE V_SOURCE_QUERY;
LOOP
    FETCH CUR_SOURCE INTO SOURCE_RECORD;

    EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;

    UPDATE A
    SET PICK_UP='Y'
    WHERE ID=SOURCE_RECORD.A_ID;

    UPDATE B
    SET PICK_UP='Y'
    WHERE ID=SOURCE_RECORD.B_ID;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: Why a slow cursor? This is better done without a loop. And why a cross join between the two tables to be updated to find the IDs?

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. I am looking for only those rows which common in both the tables based on certain condition written in ref cursor query. Once those rows identifies, I am updating back these rows.

Comment: you don't need a cursor or dynamic SQL for that. It would be much more helpful if you can [edit] your question and add the complete definition of the tables as `create table` statements, some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Reason behind that, These tables A & B keep changing. There could be some other tables as well C & D and their WHERE condition can defer as well. So, I prepare dynamic sql which running for two tables and whatever common rows I am updating back on respective tables for reconciliation.